# Why can't I connect to my ip?

Tags: windows-vista, ip, localhost, hosts

What I have is:

- Windows Vista
- Xaamp Server
- Huawei 3G USB modem

The problem is that I can't connect to my IP, although I can connect to "127.0.0.1", I've even disabled the firewall and still can't connect, I don't know if my IP is not a real IP.

Any one had the same problem, and what's the solution? Or is there any software  to buy a permanent IP & point it to my computer to both connect & receive upcoming connections?

p.s., I can't host games either.

Comment: You're probably behind a NAT. Or perhaps your ISP is blocking port 80. Or Apache is only listening on the loopback address. Could be a number of things.

Comment: Nimmy i think you are right about being behind a NAT network, how to solve this?

Comment: If you are behind a NAT your IP would be 192.168.x.x. You could probably do some type of port forwarding on your router. However, I think best bet---being that you're using cellular data plan---is that your ISP is blocking port 80.

Comment: Elaborated on my comment below. Hope this helps. And PS: I'm assuming you meant XAMPP server.

Comment: @user23392 Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me elaborate on my comment:

**1. Is Apache only listening to 127.0.0.1?**

You could test this by typing the following in the command line:

```
>netstat -a -b -n
```

Find the line with *httpd.exe*:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             WINDOWS-PC:0         LISTENING
 [httpd.exe]
```

If the address is 0.0.0.0, then apache is listening on all interfaces. If it's 127.0.0.1, then you'll have to configure it to listen on all interfaces. To do this on XAMPP:

1. Go to your XAMPP folder's Apache configuration folder (XAMPP\apache\conf).
2. Edit **httpd.conf**'s **Listen** line to be **Listen 80**
3. Restart XAMPP (Apache specifically)

---

**2. Or are you behind a NAT?**

Doubt this could be it because, even if you are behind a NAT, you should get a connection to Apache from your own computer. But still worth checking out.

Go to command line (Start -> Run -> cmd) and type the following:

```
>ipconfig
```

If your modem's IP is either 192.168.x.x, 172.x.x.x or 10.x.x.x; you're behind a NAT and would have to configure the router to do IP forwarding. This might be difficult/impossible if you don't control you're router.

---

**3. Or, you're ISP is blocking port 80:**

Finally, if you're **not** behind NAT and you're listening on all interfaces, baring some firewall misconfiguration, odds are your ISP is blocking port 80. You're simply SOL :-/

Comment: And most modems don't allow backlooping...

Comment: Really? Was not aware of that. Nice to know.